# How do I combined two onclick functions and only run it if somebody clicks "OK", not "Cancel"?

Tags: javascript

I have a link like this:

```
<a class="" onclick="delete_image('imageidentifier', 1, 0); 
return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?');">Delete Image</a>
```

Now, the problem is that the image is deleted anyways if somebody clicks cancel. How do I prevent that?

Comment: You start by not writing code inside markup. Then it gets a whole lot easier.

Comment: `confirm('...') && delete_image('...')`

Comment: put the confirm _before_ the delete_image command

Comment: @dandavis Are you sure? That won't do what OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Vohuman: then why did you put the prompt before the command in the code you posted? ;)

Comment: @dandavis If that snippet is what you meant to suggest, yes, that will work. ;)

Comment: The problem is that the code is dynamically generated, with a unique image identifier, so I can't really put it with the general .js file

Comment: @user1227914 You can store the generated value in an attribute and then read it in your click handler. Done!

Comment: @dandavis simply switching the order won't fix it.

Comment: I switched the order but that worked for the confirmation but it didn't run the delete_image afterwards :(

Comment: @user1227914 either use a conditional like in my answer or use the `&&` to short circuit it like in Vohuman's comment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that :)

Comment: @user1227914 ... Respect My Authoritah provided right answer just put prefix `javascript:` like : `onclick="javascript:*and his anwser*"`. Tested in fiddle and working ok : https://jsfiddle.net/z7mr0nkd/

Comment: the main idea is that you need to use the conditional before you run the delete command, the specifics can vary; you can use an if, &&, or return early, but the prompt needs to come first to "steer" the flow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?')){
      delete_image('imageidentifier', 1, 0); 
}
```

But this doesn't belong in html, just create a function for it and call it inside the `onclick=''`

Comment: he can put complete code in `onclick` just like you answer but he must put prefix `javascript:` ... `onclick="javascript:*and Your code*"` ... he wrote in some of his comments that `a` are created dynamically with a unique image identifier.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. What'd prevent you from separating out the js function and  just adding a function call like so: `cautious_delete('imageidentifier')` ?

Comment: Absolutely nothing... I support Your answer, and that is best solution by my opinion... easy and clean... but my comment is based by him how he can't put in general `.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use delete_image function inside confirm, you can use third function for that:

```
<a class="" onclick="askDelete()">Delete Image</a>
```

```js
function askDelete() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?')) {
    delete_image('imageidentifier', 1, 0);
  }
}
```

but better would be add event on this link inside .js:

```
<a class="foo">Delete Image</a>
```

```js
document.querySelector('.foo').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?')) {
    delete_image('imageidentifier', 1, 0);
 }
});
```